# Unable to change the default image for products in Magento 2.1.8

Tags: magento-2.1

We have a site which is currently running on Magento 2.1.8 and are running into problems with image changling within the catalog. If we make a change to the base, small, thumbnail image for a product it does not seem to be reflected on the frontend. We have tried various admin functions to resolve but nothing seems to have an impact.

To recreate this we go to a product in admin and upload a new image. Click the image we just added and select the options for this to be Base, Small, Thumbnail, Swatch. Click save and on the frontend browse to the catalog and see that the image for the product is unchanged.

Clear cache from admin has no impact, running a cache clear from CLI does not have an impact. Even running a rebuild of the image cache does not seem to resolve the issue. We have tried restarting Apache, Varnish and disabling CDN and are out of things to try.

Is this a known issue in 2.1.8 or are there any other ideas on what might be holding that now out of date reference view of the product

Comment: This issue seems to be much more significant than initially thought. It seems that no edits on products are being reflected on the frontend. I made a change to a test product title and this did not immediately reflect on the site. Tried to clear cache from admin, cli, even restarted the entire web server and am not seeing that change reflected in the catalog

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy such as cloudflare? Can ignore this I see you found a solution below.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this issue for future generations, be careful with the scope of product attributes. In our case, the catalog was seeded from a Bitnami image which had images, name and descriptions scoped to the Store level. When editing, Magento defaults to Global scope which is fine for us because we actually only have one active store. However, edits to those store level attributes do not cascade down which is why we saw no changes.

Ended up setting the scope to Global on everything and running through a bunch of product saves to get those changes to cascade across.